# How to get value of span class?

Tags: javascript

[image]

I  want to assign the date to a variable  I have tried with 
var $x = document.getElementsByTagName("span").innerHtml but this assigns null value

Comment: theres no `getElementByTagName` - theres `getElement*s*ByTagName`, but that returns a `NodeList`.

Comment: look at using `querySelector()` or `getElementsByClassName()`. `getElementByTagName` isn't a valid method as you are missing an 's', and will return a collection regardless if you used it (so innerHTML  won't work on its return value)

Answer (score 0):

You can get value with selector too.

```
document.querySelector("{SELECTOR}").innerHTML;
```

You can copy any selector with right click from Chrome Developer Console.